# GO - parse mysql json to array of strings

Tags: mysql, json, go

There is such struct:

```
Programs struct {
    ID                  int      `json:"id"`
    ShortName           string   `json:"short_name"`
    ProgramPoints       float64  `json:"program_points"`
    Countries           []string `json:"countries"`
}
```

The column `countries` is JSON column which contains array of countries `["US","GB"]`
Parsing:

```
    stmt, err := db.Query(sql)
    err = stmt.Scan(
            &program.ID,
            &program.ShortName,
            &program.ProgramPoints,
            &program.Countries)
```

Has error
`unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *`[]string
I've found the way how to parse JSON object to struct but not array. Thx in advance for any help

Comment: Looks alright to me, except for one thing: the field `countries` is not exported. `json.Marshal` (and `json.Unmarshal`) don't handle unexported fields. Change the name to `Countries` and it should work just fine

Comment: this is just an typo, the name is already capitalized

Comment: In that case, you'll need to create a type and implement the `Scan` method to unmarshal it. The values from SQL are either `string` or `[]byte`. You'll need to handle it as JSON in a custom callback, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So seeing as you're wanting the JSON value to come from the DB and be (un)marshaled automagically, you'll need to create a type for that:

```
type Programs struct {
    ID                  int       `json:"id"`
    ShortName           string    `json:"short_name"`
    ProgramPoints       float64   `json:"program_points"`
    Countries           Countries `json:"countries"`
}

type Countries []string

func (c Countries) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(c) // return json marshalled value
}

func (c *Countries) Scan(v interface{}) error {
    switch tv := v.(type) {
    case []byte:
        return json.Unmarshal(tv, &c) // unmarshal
    case []uint8:
        return json.Unmarshal([]byte(tv), &c) // can't remember the specifics, but this may be needed
    }
    return errors.New("unsupported type")
}
```

That should handle the `stmt.Scan` stuff